Is there a way to convert a local time (HHMM) to Zulu/GMT in Excel with a formula?
I have a spreadsheet of departure and arrival times in an Excel doc in a 24hr time format:



Departure Time
Arrival Time




0600
0800


1415
2355



And so on.
I also have a spreadsheet of time zones with offset values in seconds:



Timezone
Offset (Standard)
Offset (Daylight Savings)




America/New_York
-18000
-14400


Europe/Stockholm
3600
7200



The departure and arrival locations span the full globe, so the timezone offsets range from GMT-12 to GMT+12.
The issue I am running into is that I have negative and positive offsets, so the need to add or subtract changes based on location. In addition, sometimes the times would cross backwards over midnight into what Excel is treating like a negative time and returns an error (0400 in GMT+10, if I subtract 10 that returns an error, if I add 10 then that's obviously wrong; I could add 14 hours but then I have to figure out how to change all of my offsets to work for that use case and I'm not sure how to do that).
There are about 20,000 rows of these departure and arrival times, so I have been trying to come up with a formula construction that I can apply and drag down to the bottom, as it's not very practical to go line by line to make sure the formula switches between adding and subtracting hours based on the location. My Excel skills, as you can probably guess by this point, are not particularly advanced. I feel like I need to have some kind of logic test in my formula to make this work, but I know very little about using IF, etc. or if that's even the right path to be going down.
Can anyone help? I am happy to clarify anything if I have explained poorly above.
This is in Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20550) 64-bit.

You can add date in arrival and departure time to solve the negative time issue.

given a time & date you can subtract to find an earlier time & date.

A quick fix if you just want to end up with a time is to use the mod function, so it would be =mod(time+offset/3600/24,1). That would make sense to me if these are schedules maybe and don't have a specific date. Is 1475 a typo by the way? –
Tom Sharpe

"The issue I am running into is that I have negative and positive offsets, so the need to add or subtract changes based on location" Not really, as the offset already contains a sign you don't have to care anymore, if you want to add or substract. Just always substract the exact value of the offset (converted to hours) inclusive its sign. Ie in your case you want from local to UTC you have to do 8:00 - (-5 hours) (for New York) you will get 13:00 UTC

The best way to resolve this task is to manipulate with the real DateTime value to let Excel to calculate everything:

Convert string time to time of the day and add any date.
Subtract the time zone offset to get GMT.
Display the time only in appropriate format.
Determine the day difference.


C2 =DATE(2024,9,16)+TIME(LEFT(A2,2),RIGHT(A2,2),0)
D2 =C2-B2/86400
E2 =D2
F2 =INT(D2)-INT(C2)

The number format for E2 is "hhmm".
F2 just demonstrate how to determine the day offset between two DateTimes. It the timetable, you should determine the arrival day offset as the difference between the DateTime of arrival and the DateTime of departure.
